# How make a drop down menu reflect what's stored in it's corresponding db column in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How do I make a drop down menu reflect what's stored in it's corresponding column in a database?

I have a dropdown menu for gender selection and it updates the database fine
but goes back to default option in select menu on refresh where as all my text fields are pulling db data fine.

```
<%= form_for @profile, :remote => true,  do |f| %>
Username: <%= @profile.user.username %><br />
URL: http://site.com/<%= @profile.user.username %><br />
First Name: <%= f.text_field :first_name,   %><br />
Last Name: <%= f.text_field :last_name,  %><br />
I am: <%= f.select :gender, options_for_select([['Select Gender', ''],['Male','m'],['Female','f']]) %><br />
<%= f.submit 'update' %><br />
<% end %>
```

Any clue what I'm missing?
Kind regards

Here's my model:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

   attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :gender, :motd

  # Local Variables
  # Regex Variables
  email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  alpha_regex = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/
  alpha_numeric_regix = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$/


    #Form Validation
    validates :first_name,    :presence      => true,
                              :length        => { :minimum => 2, :maximum => 15 },
                              :format        => {
                                                  :with => alpha_regex,
                                                  :message => "Your first name must contain letters only"
                                                }

    validates :last_name,     :presence      => true,
                              :length        => { :minimum => 2, :maximum => 15 },
                              :format        => {  
                                                  :with => alpha_regex,
                                                  :message => "Your last name must contain letters only"
                                                }

    validates :gender,        :presence      => true,
                              :inclusion     => { 
                                                  :in => %w( m f ), :message => "Are you male or female?"
                                                }


end
```

Update method from controller

```
 def update

   respond_to do |format|

     if @profile.update_attributes(params[:profile])

       format.js   { render :js => "window.location = '#{settings_edit_profile_path}'" } 
       flash[:success] = "Profile updated" 
     else
      format.js   { render :form_errors }

    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I see nothing obviously wrong with the code fore the view. Anything unusual about the model? A custom getter for #gender or something?

Comment: Added model code to post

Comment: OK -- nothing odd in the model either. I'm guessing we would also find nothing strange in the controller, but I guess it's worth asking. Any special JavaScript that could be clearing out the value, perhaps?

Comment: Added my update method from controller. It refreshes so I didn't think that would affect it.

Comment: OK -- I got nothin'. Perhaps, this exchange will be enough to give someone else some more ideas though.

Comment: When you say "on refresh", are you reloading the page or submitting the form and coming back to it or...?

Comment: Refreshing the whole page after update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

options_for_select has a special syntax for selecting a value:

```
<%= f.select :gender, options_for_select([['Select Gender', ''],['Male','m'],['Female','f']], "#{@profile.gender}") %>
```

might work like you expect.

Or you could create a Gender model and use collection_select which does this by default:

```
<%= f.collection_select :gender, Gender.all, :value, :description, :prompt => true %>
```

Comment: Thanks, the first piece of code worked perfectly! I just removed user from the call because gender is in my profiles table.

Comment: One more thing, to_s isn't necessary forgot #{} does this already.